# How to add Label on Bar Button Item?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

I have `UIBarButtonItem` which is taken using interface builder.

Its outlet is taken as follow :

```
{
    IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *itemNext, *itemPrevious, *itemSubmit;
}
```

so in my storyboard it looks like as following image.

[image]

Now, my question is how can i add `UILabel` just before `rightBarButtonItem` item ?

**Note** : `UIBarButtonItem` is not on the `navigationController` its set on the bottom of the screen as shown in the image.

i am unable to drag and drop the `UILabel` on `UIBarButtonItem` anyone can suggest me how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UILabel` can only be added as a subview to `UIToolbar` or `UINavigationBar`.

You can add a `UIBarItem`. Use `setTitleTextAttributes:forState:` on `UIBarItem` to get attributed string properties similar to `UILabel`.